# Need help to generate a tikz graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am very new at tikz or any type of latex graphics. I need to generate a latex graphics for this diagram. can anyone help me?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:
[image]

That you will able to draw such images yourself, please start read TikZ manual. At least chapter `TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm`!

Above images was generated by the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,chains,positioning,shadows}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                > = angle 90,
    node distance = 8 mm,
      start chain = going right,
every join/.style = ->,
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw,
                     inner xsep=2mm, inner ysep=1mm,
                     text width = 33mm, align=left,
                     fill=white, drop shadow,
                     on chain,
                     join},
                        ]
\node   {Traditional Interface\\
         Tutorial A\\
         Task 1\\
         Task 2\\
         Task 3};
\node   {Timed Interface\\
         Tutorial B\\
         Task 1\\
         Task 2\\
         Task 3};
\node   {VidCom Interface\\
         Tutorial C\\
         Task 1\\
         Task 2\\
         Task 3};   
    \end{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \end{document}
```